Kernel 5.15 working but 5.8 does not?
I recently got Ubuntu dual boot.
Reasons being i want to try the fragattack:
https://github.com/vanhoefm/fragattacks?tab=readme-ov-file
In the documentation kernel 5.8 is supported and not later versions.
When i change to boot that version in bios im stuck on the Lenovo logo, while 5.15 boots up in less than a second.
I did change grub default to 5.8 which ofc resulted in no change.

While waiting for answers i will check if my disk partation could be the reason. I will update

Update: memory on ram and disk are in good margins

Recovery mode with cleaning of space gave no result, will keep updating

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details. but the 5.8 kernel was from Ubuntu 20.10 which is years beyond its EOL.
